# H1 tag and P tag on the same line?

Tags: css

I'm trying to place some text inside the P tag after the closing H1 tag like this:

**Headline** And here are the text right after....

But I can't get it to work. I made this CSS, but something is perhaps missing?

CSS:

```
p.start {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline;
}

h1.start {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="containerIntro">
    <h1 class="start">Headline </h1>
    <p class="start">Text......</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vwC6z/ :) What browser do you use?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with your code. Should work. Add a closing </div>​ just to be sure.

Comment: Can you put up a live demo somewhere? It sounds like there might be some other styles overriding these but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So if you had:

```
<div id="containerIntro">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>And here the text right after...</p>
</div>
```

Your CSS would have to look something like this:

```
#containerIntro h1,
#containerIntro p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/F3Bcd/3/.

Comment: Strange! When I made a copy of your HTML- and CSS code, I got the oppesite! Like this: And here the text right after... Headline

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this work, but there might be some other things that make it not working for me. I have to take a closer look to all of my code.

Comment: 3D-kreativ, Maybe you need to look into a CSS reset.  It will make your CSS much more predictable, even across browsers.

Comment: @3D-kreativ It sounds like something else is interfering. Is there anything else in the CSS referencing `.start`, perhaps setting `float: right;`? Or is `direction: rtl;` being set somewhere? On the subject of reset stylesheets I rather like http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

Answer (score 6):

Both `<p>` and `<h1>` elements are block level - that means they take up the complete width of their container.  You can try floating both elements to the left.  This stacks them up on each other to the left side and also converts them to inline elements.

Comment: I updated my answer, try float.  That always works for me with block-level elements.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this work, but there might be some other things that make it not working for me. I have to take a closer look to all of my code

Answer (score 0):

it would be more easy if you can also show your HTML. I am just guessing right now.

```
h1.start {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to something like this:

```
p.start {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
text-align: justify;
width: 200px;
float: left;
}

h1.start {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 28px;
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new tag in CSS with the desired attributes and values or edit an existing one (ex: .address). Then put the text you want to be inline under that tag and that's it.

After that the code should look like this:

```
containerIntro h1,

containerIntro address //(in our case) 

{display: inline;}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve that in **ONE LINE with the simplest way**

If you won't to strictly use h1 and p only and you want to achieve this :

**Headline** And here are the text right after....,
change your html to this:

html:

```
<p><b="seems-h1">Headline</b>the text right after....</P>
```

And then increase the font-size of b in css with the help of class so it seems like h1

css:

```
.seems-h1{font-size: 32px;}
```

I think this is the simplest way to do this **maybe not that efficient**, use if you want to done work quickly.

Comment: This is not a good idea because it takes away the semantics of using `<h1>`.