# div being pushed down in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to prevent green div (`.c`) being  pushed down, outside the container.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLpPRM?editors=1100

```
<section>
 <div class="a">aaaaaaaa</div>
 <div class="b">bbbbb</div>
 <div class="c">ccccccccc</div>
</section>

section
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  width: 500px
  height: 200px
  background-color: peru

.a
  width: 400px
  height: 100px
  background-color: gray
.b
  width: 100px
  height: 200px
  background-color: tan

.c
  background-color: green
  height: 100px
  width: 300px
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977390/set-flexbox-children-to-have-different-heights-to-use-up-available-space

Comment: Just change the `flex-wrap` property to `no-wrap`

Answer (score 1):

Its

```
section {
   flex-wrap: no-wrap
 }
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: peru;
}

.a {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: tan;
}

.c {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="a">aaaaaaaa</div>
<div class="b">bbbbb</div>
<div class="c">ccccccccc</div>
</section>
```