# Flex columns without setting height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a simple mega menu using existing markup of a simple unordered list without changing up the markup.

Some requirements...

- Width is fixed (in my case 100% spanning from left to right) and cannot overflow
- Height can be variable depending on the number of items, but is ideally as small as possible so we don't have just a single column with a ton of items
- First LI element needs to be 100% height due to a design restriction by the client (essentially the first LI will be a highlighted link in the first column and the remaining items are the rest of the navigation items listed vertically in columns.

Here is a quick simplified mockup of the general layout...
[image]

Right now I've been able to accomplish most of this with flex, but am having to set a height on the whole container before it starts to wrap into columns and then run into an overflow issue at the right if the content is larger.  Here is a simplified example...

```css
.megamenu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.6em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 210px;
}

.megamenu .item {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.megamenu .item:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAEAD6;
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3 with an extra long string of text for testing purposes</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 12 Quam Nibh Cursus Ornare Adipiscing</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 24 Amet Tellus Lorem Ligula Euismod</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 25</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 26</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 27</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 28 Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 29</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 30</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not entirely sure it's possible to use flex to accomplish this, but I've tried with grid and plain old columns, but neither worked well.

Comment: wouldnt the use of the column-attribute HTML wise a possibility for you?

Comment: Flex might not work. Try using column layout and set a page break on second item.

Comment: This question was just marked as a duplicate referencing "CSS-only masonry layout" and "Make a grid item span to the last row / column in implicit grid" but neither of these answers my question. Columns does not work because it does not allow for the full height first element and grid isn't working because of the row spacing issue as mentioned in my comment to MaxiGui's question.  As far as I can tell what I trying to do is not possible with flex, grid or column-count without grunging up the markup with DIVs.  If anyone else has a solution, though, just let me know. :)

Comment: I have reopened the question since both duplicate questions have no conclusive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the number of columns is pre-determined. The simplest solution would be to use [CSS column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns). The first item – which needs special handling – could be *positioned*.

The following example uses 3 columns. I have marked the rules that need to be changed for any other number of columns.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.megamenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.megamenu .item {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  background-color: #9BA;
}
/* column setup */
.megamenu {
  margin-left: 33.3333%; /* 3 cols => 1/3, 4 cols => 1/4 */
  column-count: 2; /* 3 cols => 2, 4 cols => 3 */
  column-gap: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.megamenu .item {
  break-inside: avoid; /* don't split border/padding/etc across columns */
}

.megamenu .item:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%; /* 3 cols => -1/2, 4 cols => -1/3 */
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FDD;
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3 with an extra long string of text for testing purposes</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 12 Quam Nibh Cursus Ornare Adipiscing</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 24 Amet Tellus Lorem Ligula Euismod</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 25</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 26</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 27</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 28 Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 29</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 30</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Flexbox rows are expected to have fixed sizes.

> Flexbox is not meant to recreate Masonry with pure CSS: items in one
> row cannot occupy space allocated for a preceding/following row (same
> goes for columns if you're using column orientation). You can use
> align-items to prevent them from stretching, but that's about it

Try:

```
.megamenu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.6em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 210px;
}

.megamenu .item {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.megamenu .item:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAEAD6;
}
```

Or you can try column orientation or the multi-column module
(see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20862961/1652962)

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution with `display: grid;`. I dont know how many columns you wish to have but it is up to you to fix that into the `grid-template-columns`.

In your container set the below code:

```css
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto [last-line];
```

In your first item set like this, it will span for the first item:

```css
/* This make the trick */
  grid-row: 1 / span last-line;
  grid-row-start: span 9000;
```

The credit belong to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052336/make-a-grid-item-span-to-the-last-row-column-in-implicit-grid#44052563). If you consider my answer to be a duplicate, please delete your question.

```css
.megamenu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.6em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto [last-line];
}

.megamenu .item {
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
}

.megamenu .item:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #FAEAD6;
  /* This make the trick */
  grid-row: 1 / span last-line;
  grid-row-start: span 9000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu">
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3 with an extra long string of text for testing purposes</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 12 Quam Nibh Cursus Ornare Adipiscing</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 24 Amet Tellus Lorem Ligula Euismod</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 25</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 26</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 27</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 28 Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 29</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 30</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The trouble I ran into with grid is that the rows align to the bottom of the largest element in the previous row.  In this example I would need "Item 5" to be right below item 2 without all the extra space even though item 3 is extra long.  Is there a way around this?  Also, the items need to stack vertically so item 3 needs to be below item 2 instead of to the right.